# Distribute a sqlite database with a BlackBerry application

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

How can I deploy my application with sqlite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your question but these articles may be helpful:

- A java.net article: [Getting Started with Java and SQLite on Blackberry OS 5.0](http://today.java.net/article/2010/03/17/getting-started-java-and-sqlite-blackberry-os-50)
- In the BlackBerry developer knowledge base: [Storing data in SQLite databases](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_data_in_SQLite_databases_1219769_11.jsp)